# Automating file copy/moving and renaming

Tags: c#, python, automation

I'm new to coding and need a bit of help... in essence I'm trying somewhat to run a bit before I've actually found my footing and gotten the basics, however I'd like to be able to copy/move/rename certain files from one specific directory to another or multiple directories.

The file formats are set up such that all files will begin with the date (reversed) followed by certain descriptors for that file  i.e. 191017_TGT.csv or 191016_APP.txt

I'm trying to find a solution for getting Python/C# to carry out the following steps:

1. Determine the source folder and destination folder
2. Identify file descriptors/types exist in source folder.
3. If it has 'A' descriptor/type and was created today copy/move to folder 'A' if 'B' copy/move to folder 'B'

That's sort of what I'm trying to do, I've been playing around with (shutil.copy) but been hitting some road blocks. I'd like to be able to automate some of the rudimentary tasks that I've got to do and speed things up a bit.

Also if anyone knows any good resources for automating tasks please let me know or any good coding basics sources in general.

Thanks!

Comment: C# [File Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=netframework-4.8) has just-about everything you need, well documented with examples.

Comment: If you are looking for suggestions on resources, I don't think SO is the right place.Please show us what you have tried with the code and where are you hitting road blocks

Comment: Will do, thanks for the direction and advise.

Comment: There's a great python book & website called [Automate the Boring Stuff](https://automatetheboringstuff.com). You may find it a useful resource.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example to get you started:

```
import fnmatch
import os
import shutil

src = r'C:\tmp\src'
dest = r'C:\tmp\dest'

for file_name in os.listdir(src):
    # match any files that start with two digits
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file_name, '[0-9][0-9]*'):
        src_name = os.path.join(src, file_name)
        dest_name = os.path.join(dest, file_name)
        shutil.copyfile(src_name, dest_name)
```

In operation:

```
C:\tmp>dir /b/s
C:\tmp\dest
C:\tmp\src
C:\tmp\test_move.py
C:\tmp\src\191016_APP.txt
C:\tmp\src\191017_TGT.csv
C:\tmp\src\dont_move.txt

C:\tmp>python test_move.py

C:\tmp>dir /b/s
C:\tmp\dest
C:\tmp\src
C:\tmp\test_move.py
C:\tmp\dest\191016_APP.txt
C:\tmp\dest\191017_TGT.csv
C:\tmp\src\191016_APP.txt
C:\tmp\src\191017_TGT.csv
C:\tmp\src\dont_move.txt
```

Note that you can do better pattern matching using [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re), but that might be a bit much to get into as a neophyte. The [fnmatch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html#module-fnmatch) pattern above will match any file that starts with two numbers.

EDIT: If for example, you wanted to move different files to different locations you could modify the script:

```
src = r'C:\tmp\src'
csv_dest = r'C:\tmp\dest_csv'
txt_dest = r'C:\tmp\dest_txt'

for file_name in os.listdir(src):
    # match any csv files that start with two digits
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file_name, '[0-9][0-9]*.csv'):
        src_name = os.path.join(src, file_name)
        dest_name = os.path.join(csv_dest, file_name)
    elif fnmatch.fnmatch(file_name, '[0-9][0-9]*.txt'):
        src_name = os.path.join(src, file_name)
        dest_name = os.path.join(txt_dest, file_name)
    else:
        print(f"Skipping {file_name}")
        dest_name = None
    if dest_name:
        shutil.copyfile(src_name, dest_name)
```

Comment: Thanks Import, I've given it a run and it works really well, it also doesn't override the data that's already there. Though if I was to add a 2nd destination folder for the files how would I add this on to the current script? Trying with and's and multiple if's but not really getting anywhere. Thanks for the help so far though, appreciate it.